# How to only free buffer cache in Linux

Tags: linux, caching, memory

I know there are page cache and buffer cache in Linux. Page cache is for file system, and buffer cache is for device.

To free pagecache:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

To free dentries and inodes:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

My question:

Is buffer cache covered in drop_caches?

If not, then is there a method to only free buffer caches, leaving the page cache still cached?

If there isn't, why it's unnecessary or impossible?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ans:-    

sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Here’s the output of free before and after running the above command.

Before

# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           502        487         15          0         15        170
-/+ buffers/cache:        301        201
Swap:         3153        375       2777
After

# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           502        345        157          0          1         44
-/+ buffers/cache:        300        202
As you can see the highlighted numbers, the buffers and cached values have dropped significantly after I ran the command. Again, this is not necessary. In fact, it’s not recommended at all but there it is if you’re curious to know.
```

Comment: But my question is how to free ONLY buffer cache, without page cache. Would you explain buffer cache and page cache?